# How remap my CapsLock key to work as if it was a Return key using setxkbmap?

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xkb

I tried several things:

```
setxkbmap -option caps: return
setxkbmap -option caps: enter
```

I also tried to modify the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` by:

```
"Key <CAPS> {[Enter]};"
```

But nothing worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if it helps (as not purely in `setxkbmap`), but:

```
setxkbmap -option caps:none
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Linefeed"
```

Change back:

```
setxkbmap -option
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Caps_Lock"
```

You can check with something like:

```
xev | sed -ne '/^KeyPress/,/^$/p'
```

to get keycodes.

Comment: While this works to insert a line break, this doesn't act a s return key. Use `xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Return"` to emulate a return key.

Comment: This answer was perfect for what I wanted to do. I wanted to rebind capslock to a key I wasn't using for anything (F1). Now I can use capslock as my tmux prefix.

Answer (score 2):

> I also tried to modify the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` by:
>
> `"Key <CAPS> {[Enter]};"`
>
> But nothing worked.

Almost there... There is no such thing as `Enter`. The keyword here is `Return` so edit your `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` like this (original line commented out with `//`):

```
// key <CAPS> {     [ Caps_Lock             ]       };
key <CAPS> {        [ Return                ]       };
```

and then your <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> should act as <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

For Gnome (and Ubuntu 18.04), you can use Gnome Tweak tool, and change it under Keyboard and Mouse settings. Click 'Additional Layout Options', and you will find settings for Caps Lock.

[image: Change Ubuntu 18.04/Gnome Caps Lock behaviour]